# Using Filter in tm_map(testfile, removeNumbers) in R?

Tags: r, tm

I am using tm_map(testfile, removeNumbers) to remove the numbers of a textfile. However, I need to retain the numbers that comes along with the words such as ipv4 and ipv6.
How can I use the removeNumbers function to remove other numbers but keep the numbers that comes with ipv4 and ipv6.?

This is the code I used:

```
test.txt = "this is a test file with numbers 1,2 and 3.
              The internet protocals ipv4 and ipv6"

library(tm)

test <- Corpus(DirSource('C:test'), readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
test <- tm_map(test, removeNumbers)

inspect(test[1])
```

Output:

```
$test.txt

this is a test file with numbers , and . The internet protocals ipv and ipv
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`removeNumbers` will remove any digit. You can get its code like this:

```
getS3method("removeNumbers","PlainTextDocument")
function (x) 
gsub("[[:digit:]]+", "", x)
```

You should create a new function that remove "alone" digits , or digits after spaces.

```
remove_alone_nbr <- 
function (x) 
  gsub('\\s*(?<!\\B|-)\\d+(?!\\B|-)\\s*', "", x,perl=TRUE)
```

Then if you test it :

```
inspect(tm_map(Corpus(VectorSource(test.txt)), remove_alone_nbr))
```

You get :

```
this is a test file with numbers,and.
              The internet protocals ipv4 and ipv6
```

Comment: As `remove_alone_nbr("I love 33 things but I am committed to 3: ipv6 and ipv4 and S6")` produces ` "I lovethings but I am committed to: ipv6 and ipv4 and S6"` one may want to replace numbers with white spaces instead of empty strings.